# How to convert the ordinary image into effective image in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-fireworks, photo-editing, cs6

I want to convert the images by the following Images Conversion Method. How do i convert in photoshop cs6 Response Me..

From[image]

To
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try creating multiple layers of the image, each with a vector/layer mask revealing one of the square areas. From there just vary the transparencies of each layer and add a little inner glow effect to give it the ghost/airbrush look. Looks like the color/contrast/saturation is tweaked a little also.

Comment: ok i will try this in Photoshop. Any possiblilty  convert the images in adobe fireworks